# Какова максимальная длина строки ключа (свойства) объекта?

Tags: javascript

```js
var obj = {};
var str = 'имя_свойства';

for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    str += str;
}

console.log('длина: ' + str.length);
obj[str] = 1;
console.log('значение: ' + obj[str]);
```

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли так делать?
2. Есть ли ограничения на размеры?
3. Влияет ли это как то на производительность? Или лучше хранить значения в массиве и проверять равенство проходя циклом?

Comment: Ключ может быть довольно большим, для вашего браузера можете проверить тут http://output.jsbin.com/nixafu/13/

Comment: Ну раз работает, значит можно. Нигде не встречал ограничение на длину ключа. Только рекомендую по возможности использовать `Object.create(null)` вместо `{}` для словарей.

Comment: @Qwertiy
А почему нельзя {}?

Comment: Можно. Пока где-нибудь не попадётся `key='toString'; obj[key]` :)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, если это ответ, то стоит написать ответ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ispropertykey) ключом свойства может быть либо строка либо Symbol. Ограничений на используемую строку не накладывается.

При этом, в самом типе [String](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) указано следующее:

> The String type is the set of all ordered sequences of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integer values (“elements”) up to a maximum length of 2<sup>53</sup>-1 elements

> тип String - это набор всех возможных последовательностей из 0 или более 16-битных беззнаковых целых значений (элементов) максимальной длиной до 2<sup>53</sup>-1 элементов.

Так же конкретное значение может зависеть от конкретной реализации движка.

---

На производительность это влияет так же как и любое другое достаточно большое выделение памяти