# Объекты и их ключи

Tags: javascript

### TypeScript

```js
{
    let foo = function () { }
    let o = {}
    o[foo] = 'test string'
    console.log(`o[foo]: ${o[foo]}`)
    // Type '() => void' cannot be used as an index type.
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### документация мозиллы

[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Сходство_объектов_и_map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_map)

> - В объекте ключи должны быть строками, когда в Map они могут иметь любой тип.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared

> - The keys of an Object are Strings and Symbols, whereas they can be any value for a Map, including functions, objects, and any primitive.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Parameters

> Pairs of names (strings) and values (any value) where the name is separated from the value by a colon.

[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Параметры](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

> Пары из имён (строки) и значений (любые значения), где имя отделяется от значения двоеточием.

### Вопрос:

1. пруфы на ecmascript? или ...
   а вообще кого считать авторитетным источником ?
   да, есть ли у хрома анлог документации MDN ?
2. возможно какие-либо рекомендации от разработчиков(хрома) ?
3. а как оно вообще работает ?

например в приведённом ниже коде ключ `[arr]` это ссылка ?
если да - а как там со сборщиком мусора и доступом из корня ? ( на сегодня, жеж, вроде как победили перекрёстные ссылки. тема отдельного вопроса, но всё же, если кто в курсе - прошу поделиться ходя бы ссылками. например отредактировав это вопрос)

```js
{
    let el = function () {
        let t = Date.now()
        document.body.innerHTML += `<table id="log${t}"></table>`
        return document.getElementById('log' + t)
    }()
    let log = (_f = '<hr>') => 'string' == typeof _f
        ? el.innerHTML += `<tr> <td><hr></td> <td>${_f}</td></tr>`
        : el.innerHTML += `<tr> <td>${_f.toString()}</td> <td>${_f()}</td></tr>`
    // ---
    let arr = ['a']
    let o = {
        [arr]: 'test'
    }
    // --
    log(() => o[['a']])
    log(() => o[arr])
    log()
    arr = undefined
    log(() => o[['a']])
    log(() => o[arr])
}
```

Comment: Ключ обязательно должен быть строкой. Если он не строка, то он автоматически конвертируется в строку — всё очень просто. `o[foo]` это абсолютно то же самое, что ли `o["function () { }"]`

Comment: Аналогично в следующем примере, `o[arr]` или `o[[arr]]` это то же самое что и `o["a"]`

Comment: окей а объекты?

Comment: Что объекты?. .

Comment: `{
    class A{};class B{};
    let o = {[A]:'test string1',[B]:'test string2',}
    console.log(o[A]);
    console.log(o[B]);
}`

Comment: Всё полностью аналогично, `o[A]` это то же самое что и `o["class A{}"]` и так далее

Comment: да, с конструкторами не удачно. окей, если я создам объект, использую его как ключ(он магически превратится в строку), потом изменю этот объект(ключ) и что? всё поломается? ключ больше не подойдёт7

Comment: @qwabra а что должно поломаться? Во первых строки передаются всегда по значению, во вторых в объекте так и будет первоначальное св-во

Comment: @qwabra и ничего, (почти) любой объект при переводе в строку выдаёт `"[object Object]"`, и следовательно (почти) любые объекты будут являться одинаковым ключом

Comment: Как вы сами указали в вопросе, для ключей любого типа следует использовать Map, там никаких переводов в строки не будет и всё будет хорошо

Comment: В чем смысл примера кода и ошибки из TypeScript, если вопрос про javascript?

Comment: @andreymal, покрутил, вы совершенно правы. почему-то считал что в качестве ключа передаётся ссылка

Comment: @qwabra вот в Map скорее всего как раз ссылка (но я Map не юзал и точно не знаю)

Comment: @Grundy, в том что раньше так делал а тут поломалося :)

Comment: @Grundy продолжаем буянить? При чём тут длина ключа?

Comment: @andreymal, вот как раз читая манул на мап я и задумался. (В объекте ключи должны быть строками, когда в Map они могут иметь любой тип.
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    let foo = function () { }
    let o = {}
    o[foo] = 'test string'
    console.log(`o[foo]: ${o[foo]}`)
    // Type '() => void' cannot be used as an index type.
}
```

Ну и что вам тут не нравится, написано же:

> В объекте ключи должны быть строками, когда в Map они могут иметь
>   любой тип.

Вы попробуйте вывести объект, который написали

```
const prop1 = 10
const prop2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const prop3 = {a: 1}
const test = {[prop1]: 'prop1', [prop2]: 'prop2', [prop3]: 'prop3'}
// {1,2,3,4: "prop2", 10: "prop1", [object Object]: "prop3"}
```

То есть в данном случае, просто неявно вызывается метод `toString`, либо считает значение переменной. Таким образом можно передавать динамически ключи:

```
const prop = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'more': 'less';
const test2 = {[prop]: true};
```

Про `Map` отдельная тема, но это и не объект совсем, а скорее новая структура. И ключи там могут быть чем угодно, хоть функцией, хоть объектом. Тут работает обычное сравнение по значению/ссылке

```
const mapProp = {'prop': 1}
const test3 = new Map();
test3.set(mapProp, true);
test3.get(mapProp)
// true
// объект схож
const mapProp2 = {'prop': 1}
// но это не работает
test3.get(mapProp2)
// undefined
```

> а вообще кого считать авторитетным источником ?

Спецификацию: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html

Comment: [там](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/844398/232932) Grundy приводит  более точную ссылку http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ispropertykey